# character problem in sql

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

```
select * from table where key='çmyk'
```

when i run this query on table that have row which's value is 'cmyk'.

the query returns me that row. but values are different. when i search 'çmyk' it returns 'cmyk'.

so what can i do?

MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci
table collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `latin1_swedish_ci` collation is not only case insensitive, it is umlaut insensitive as well, so the following applies:

```
Ä = A
Ö = O
etc.
```

switching to a case sensitive collation in the WHERE clause should work, like so:

```
select * from table where key='çmyk' collate latin1_general_cs;
```

with the caveat that this is not good for performance.

mySQL Reference: [9.1.7.8. Examples of the Effect of Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try running the command `SET NAMES latin1;` and then running your query.